# Is there a way to have my elements(icons, fonts) change while scrolling and then change back when scrolling stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a one page design that I have been working on and I want to change certain elements while scrolling, but have them revert back when scrolling stops. I have tried using the scrollTop function as shown below, but this changes the item indefinitely.

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  var fromTopPx = 20;
  var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
  if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
  jQuery('.homeicon').addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
 }else{
  jQuery('.homeicon').removeClass('fa-angle-double-down');
        }
       });
```

```css
.homeicon {
    padding: 100px 5px 1000px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <i class="homeicon fa fa-home fa-2x">
  </i>
   <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, it is totally easy to accomplish, what you need is to debounce the function that switch the icon back, `lodash` provides a function for this.

here is the result. for more info check the debounce documentation.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce

note: using this approach is easier because this avoids to do magic calculations.

```js
const switchBack = () => {
  jQuery('.homeicon').removeClass('fa-angle-double-down');
}

const debounced = _.debounce(switchBack, 250);

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
  // when scrolling we set the class to be the one we want when scrolling (haha)
  jQuery('.homeicon').addClass('fa-angle-double-down');
  // also we run our debounced function.
  // it will run 250ms after we stop calling it.
  debounced();
});
```

```css
.homeicon {
  padding: 100px 5px 1000px 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <i class="homeicon fa fa-home fa-2x">
  </i>
  <span>Home</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been looking for something like this for awhile.